# Comparing arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have String Array of a good couple hundred lines of code. I have two other String Arrays, one with values I want to replace, and the other with the value I want it to replace to. I need to go through each line of the original code and check each line if it contains anything that I need to replace, and if it does, replace it. I want to replace it to a totally different String Array, so that the original is still left unchanged. This is what I have, but it's not exactly working.

```
for(int i=0; i<originalCode.length; i++) {

    if( originalCode[i].contains("| "+listOfThingsToReplace[i]) ) {

        newCode[i]=originalCode[i].replaceAll(("| "+listOfThingsToReplace[i]), ("| "+listOfReplacingThings[i]));

    }

}
```

Obviously I need more counting variables somewhere (especially because `originalCode.length !=listOfThingsToReplace.length`), but I can't figure out where. Would I need more for loops? I tired doing that... but "`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`"... Any help please?

Comment: Use `replace()` which replaces all occurrences of plain-text, not `replaceAll()` which replaces all occurrences of a regex match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick if I'm understanding the problem correctly

```js
// New Code Array
String[] newCode = new String[originalCode.length];

for (int i=0; i<originalCode.length; i++) {
 // New Code Line
 String newCodeLine = originalCode[i];

 // Iterate through all words that need to be replaced
 for (int j=0; j<listOfThingsToReplace.length; j++) {
  
  // String to replace
  String strToReplace = listOfThingsToReplace[j];
  
  // String to replace with
  String strToReplaceWith = (j >= listOfReplacingThings.length) ? "" : listOfReplacingStrings[j];
  
  // If there is a string to replace with
  if (strToReplaceWith != "") {
   
   // then replace all instances of that string
   newCodeLine = newCodeLine.replaceAll(strToReplace, strToReplaceWith);
  }  
 }
 
 // Assign the new code line to our new code array
 newCode[i] = newCodeLine;
}
```

Comment: Use `!strToReplaceWith.equals("")` instead of `!=`. Plus that part doesn't even make sense; how could j be greater than the length when you have the check in your for loop.

Comment: You're right about the .equals, I always forget about that. I put the check with j to handle the situation where listofReplacingThings.length is less than listOfThingsToReplace.length, but may or may not be necessary